# How to grab IP:PORT with regex?

Tags: php, regex, ip, port

I'm creating a small IP:PORT scraper in PHP. The problem is that I'm pretty unfamiliar with RegEx.

So I've been piecing together what I can.

Here's what I've got:
`/\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):([0-9]{1,5})\b/`

I know this isn't the best. At least not the end to grab the port, because it means that ports will be able to be things like 99999.

Also, it seems to return two matches this way. The IP:PORT and the PORT. I just need it to grab the full IP:PORT, not one or the other.

Comment: is port not everything after : ?

Comment: @Dagon: No, it just be a few integers after it. (1-5 integers)

Comment: What do the input strings look like? i.e. where are you actually try to grab them *from*?

Comment: @DaveRandom, various webpages, in which the HTML varies greatly.

Comment: ...and are you trying to grab them out of full URLs (like `http://IP:PORT/some/stuff`), or are they just `IP:PORT` on their own? Come to that, will there always be a `:PORT` section or might some of them just be `IP`?

Comment: They're usually just alone, but might have some sort of HTML directly before or after. Not full URLs usually, though it's possible. There IS always a :PORT section.

Comment: you may try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25866412/3767784

Answer (score 5):

Your regex is fine so I will just concentrate on the port itself. This regex :

```
(?::                #Match the :
  (?![7-9]\d\d\d\d) #Ignrore anything above 7....
  (?!6[6-9]\d\d\d)  #Ignore anything abovr 69...
  (?!65[6-9]\d\d)   #etc...
  (?!655[4-9]\d)
  (?!6553[6-9])
  (?!0+)            #ignore complete 0(s)
  (?<Port>\d{1,5})
)?
```

Will optionally catch any valid port number and store it to named group port.

Note: *free spacing* must be enabled:

```
if (preg_match(
    '/\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
    (?::
      (?![7-9]\d\d\d\d) #Ignrore anything above 7....
      (?!6[6-9]\d\d\d)  #Ignore anything abovr 69...
      (?!65[6-9]\d\d)   #etc...
      (?!655[4-9]\d)
      (?!6553[6-9])
      (?!0+)            #ignore complete 0(s)
      (?P<Port>\d{1,5})
    )?
    \b/x', 
    $subject)) {
    # Successful match
}
```

Comment: How can I be sure free spacing is enabled?

Comment: @Rob /x in the end of the regex.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):\d{1,5}\b
```

There are a few examples for IP matching [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html).  Just take any of them and put `:\d{1,5}\b` on the end (to match a port).

Comment: Yeah but wouldn't that then match ports like 99999?

Comment: Regular Expressions aren't quite [turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).  You can use some PHP to figure out if the port is completely legal or not.  Or you can put all the number ranges in there if you like. EDIT: See Fallen's solution for ports.  I still recommend doing that part in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

I've posted a regular expression below what matches either ip or ip and port.

```
$ip = '111.222.333.444';
if ( preg_match('/([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\:?([0-9]{1,5})?/', $ip, $match) ) {
   echo 'ip: ' . $match['1'] . (isset($match['2']) ? ' port: ' . $match['2'] : '');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**FailedDev's Port portion of his answer** - shortened it a bit and set boundaries, this will only catch the port

```
\b(?![7-9]\d{4})(?!6[6-9]\d{3})(?!65[6-9]\d{2})(?!655[4-9]\d)(?!6553[6-9])(?!0+)(\d{1,5})\b
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this long time ago.

```
[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}:[0-9]{5}
```

Comment: Why would you use [0-9]? I can't imagine an IP being 999.999.999.999 or anywhere close. As it stands now, the one I provided in my question is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Pattern/Regex works for all scenarios, it gives you the output of only valid IPV4 format IP-Address & Port number
'`'^([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,4})(:[0-9]{1,4})?$'`

### My Input:

`10.128.16.38:22`

`1050:0000:0000:0000:0005:0600:300c:326b:22`

`11.11.11.11`

`asdfasdf`

`1012312101231210123121012312101231210123121012312101231210123121012312`

`10.128.45.23:9095`

`10.128.16.27:22 asdfasdfasdf`

`as@#$@#$`

`1050:0000:0000:0000:0005:0600:3002:3260:90`

`10.128.46.00:`

### Output: (Only Valid Ip:Port):

`10.128.16.38:22`

`10.128.45.23:9095`